# Calling jsf custom validator on event

Tags: java, validation, jsf, events

Is it possible to perform custom validator invocation (under `<f:validator validatorId="myCustomValidator">` tag) before submitting the form?
I would like to validate an `<h:inputText>` field dynamically when any onblur (or similar one) action is fired and then perform `myCustomValidator`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a javascript function that validates any onblur events on the client side, or if by chance you are using primefaces for the frontend then you can use `<p:ajax event="blur" update="ids_to_be_updated" listener="your_server_method"/>` on the server side to validate.